# C# generic types typedef/alias and InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, generics, types, alias

Using generic types of generic types becomes badly readable, so I want to create a shorter alias. For Example:

1) In this case via subclassing.

```
public class Parameters : Dictionary<string, string> {};
```

To me this is really just an alias, so at some point I want to do:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>;
// some operations on myDictionary
Parameters parameters = (Parameters)myDictionary;
```

There I get an InvalidCastOperation, I assume since I want to cast from baseclass to inherited class (my "trick" to get an alias).

Unfortunately, this also is not allowed to save the day:

```
public class Parameters : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public static implicit operator Parameters(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        Parameters res = new Parameters();
        foreach (var parameter in dict)
            res.Add(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
        return res;
    }
};
```

does not compile. So this looks like a dead end.

I could perhaps write my own method that I would have to call explicitly, but an implicit conversion would be a lot nicer.

2) Alternatively, I can delcare on the file level:

```
using Parameters = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;
```

This has the disadvantage, that I need to declare it for each file that I want to use the type in (or use the full syntax).

How can I get an alias that does have implicit conversion and also only needs to be declared once?

**edit/add**
For better understanding, this is the actual code.

```
public delegate Parameters UrlHandler(Parameters jsonParameters);
public class RequestHandlers : Dictionary<string, UrlHandler> { };
public class Parameters : Dictionary<string, string> { };
```

The problem then comes when I do a Linq-union between 2 Parameters, which results in a Dictionary.

Comment: I would discourage you from doing this. Making a new alias for a very well-known class like `Dictionary<,>` will reduce the readability of your code instead of increasing it.

Comment: I dont want to create an alias for Dictionary, but Dictionary<string, string>. Also, this example is simplified, I also have Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> and more complex types. Though I think the cast problem will mainly occur on "simple" types like Dictionary, at least I have only encountered them there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, I don't consider aliasing a good practice. I believe that it reduces the readability of your code. However, if you think that in your particular case it will make the code more readable, **or** if you think that `Parameters` could potentially become something more than just a dictionary, you can inherit from `Dictionary<string,string>` and use its copy constructor:

```
public class Parameters : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public Parameters(IDictionary<string, string> dict) : base(dict)
    {
    }
};
```

This will allow you to do this:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Parameters parameters = new Parameters(myDictionary);
```

As well as this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = parameters;
```

Comment: That is from what I have seen and thought about the closest to an implicit conversion. Why are you against aliasing? For more clarity, I will also edit/add the real code, I think it would be rather cumbersome to both read and write.

Comment: @AndreasReiff Normally, I am against aliasing because it may be confusing to think or talk about the same entity and use two different names for it. Although I can imagine scenarios where aliasing might help, such as `Using Permissions = Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,bool>>>>`. But even in that case, I would prefer wrapping this into a separate class, since adding some helper methods may be, well, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You're clinging too much to old-school C. In C, aliases were just that - shortcuts for the name. Sure, maybe that saved you a bunch of keypresses, but that's hardly worth it nowadays, especially with features like IntelliSense.

Instead of just giving the same type a different name, you really want to make your own type which only exposes whatever is necessary for your use case. Hiding and abstracting, rather than just aliasing.

For example, you've got your `Parameters`. Do you really want all of the properties and methods of a `Dictionary<string, string>`? Do you really want to allow implicit conversions back and forth?

There's quite a few solutions that are a bit better suited for modern programming. But you need to think about what you actually want - what does it *mean* for a type to represent `Parameters`? Perhaps you want to pass around a set of parameters from somewhere, created at one point (e.g. from configuration) and only read elsewhere? Just create your own type, and expose the interface you actually want:

```
public class Parameters
{
  private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _parameters;

  public Parameters(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
  {
    _parameters = parameters;
  }

  public string this[string key]
  {
    get { return _parameters[key]; }
  }
}
```

Now you're only exposing the interface that actually matters. Do you need a way to iterate over the parameters? Just implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Do you *really* need a dictionary? Then forget using the rather concrete class of `Dictionary<string, string>`, and use the interface `IDictionary<string, string>` instead - that's something your `Parameters` class can easily implement (perhaps simply delegating to the underlying dictionary, depending on your requirements). Now you can create a new `Parameters` from a dictionary... while `Parameters` itself *remains* a dictionary, and can be used anywhere another `IDictionary<string, string>` can, no need to recast it to `Dictionary<string, string>` - why would you want to do that anyway?

Think about the error message in your casting operator attempt - "User-defined conversions to or from a base class are not allowed". Did you consider what would happen if this *didn't* cause an error? You'd break all of how inheritance and interfaces work - so your type is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, but not really? If you do an implicit cast to `Dictionary<string, string>`, it's going to make a copy, but if you do an explicit cast, it remains the same instance? Child types can always be cast to their parent's type - that's kind of the whole point of class-based OOP :)

Embrace OOP. Or FP, that's also supported by C# well enough. But sticking to C-style programming in C# is not going to work, you're just going to cause a lot of pain for everyone :)

Comment: I already caused the pain for me. :) And yes, just now I did think about adding some methods to Parameters - since I use same code in many places and since Parameters now has to be a "real" class anyway (never thought about it - see also Dmytro's answer and original suggestin of explicit conversion), this is a good idea.

Comment: @AndreasReiff It sounds like you're still in the early phases, so the pain isn't too big. I've been working with C# applications that have been written like C for years - and there's nothing quite like a C# application that's written like it's 1970s, with multi-threading and 3000 (!) `public static` fields in the `Program` class. Believe me, nipping the bud early saves you a huge amount of pain in the long run :D

Comment: Been there, done that. :) It gets less and less and still surprised how much my code can be improved. Thanks again! And also I had a colleague that was programming like this.. actually even worse.. integer-based state-machine with 50 states. :) He didnt even know what it does himself after a few days.